# Fullcalendar passing event data via ajax producing error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

I am trying to send event data via ajax to save them to database. Below is my code:

```
select: function(start, end) {
            var title = prompt('Event Title:');
            if (title) {
                calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                    {
                        title: title,
                        start: start,
                        end: end
                    },
                    true // make the event "stick"
                );
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: '/event/new',
                data: {'title': title, 'start': start, 'end':end},
                type: "POST",
                success: function (json) {
                    alert('Added Successfully');
                }
            });
            calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
        },
```

Adding event is working fine according to selected time. But I get the following error:
[image]

If I click to that error it takes me to moment.js to the following lines:

```
function locale_calendar__calendar (key, mom, now) {
        var output = this._calendar[key];
        return isFunction(output) ? output.call(mom, now) : output;
    }
```

if I delete the ajax part of code, there is no error! But off course, I need to save the event to database.
Any idea, what is wrong I am doing?

Comment: have a quick try , how about put this line --calendar.fullCalendar('unselect')-- into
ajax's success function , I think you may release the start and end information before ajax's work done .

Comment: I have tried according to your advise, But no luck! 
I guess something to do with lang (locale), But don't know what is it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this provlem by converting start and end to a JSON data. Which currently looks like as below:

```
     $.ajax({
                url: '/event/new',
                data: {'title': title, 'start': start.toJSON(), 'end':end.toJSON()},
                type: "POST",
                success: function (json) {
                    alert('Added Successfully');
                }
            });
```